# Can i trust soc.io to publish my app

Tags: android, app-store, google-play

today i came across a new app-store for Android called soc.io. The website looks very clean and simple,
but you can never trust a beautiful website. So i googled for soc.io any reviews or so, but i found nothing.
I read the whole developer teams which you have to accept if you register their, but they look trustworthy.
After that i tried to find some real apps which are in the android market too, and so i found the avg virus
scanner. It's posted on soc.io from a guy (which i found, who hold security conferences). On the market there
are some more versions of the avg scanner. Why should he only post one apk on soc.io. It looks very strange.

Has someone any experience with soc.io. Perhaps a developer who posted his apps there too.

At the moment my apps are live in the original android market, and on androidpit. When androidtapp releases 
their licensing service i will launch my apps there too. 
Soc.io has a licensing service at the moment so this should not be the problem.

I hope some of you can give me some more information about soc.io . I don't like to publish my app on a site
which is fake or not that trusty as androidPit or the real android market.

Perhaps someone knows how big the user-base from soc.io is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Seavus, more precisely at Soc.io Mall (which is a Seavus branch) as a content editor for two months now. I feel obliged to reply as there is obviously a necessity for positive feedback regarding Soc.io Mall. So here it is: 
Basically my job is to test apps when they are posted and to Okay or Reject them if they do not fulfill acceptance norms (posted on the site). These two months we had lot of apps (free and paid) downloaded and no complaints whatsoever on the matter of money(The Support team is 2 meters away from me). I'm sure you can check Seavus online more then you can check Soc.io Mall and see that this is a serious company that is also a factor in software development. 
Hope I'll get the chance test your apps. All the best. And also admin: hope you don't treat this as spam.Because it's not.:)

Answer (score 1):

I made a little research on the app stores market and found out they Soc.io Mall have around 50 000 registered users. Regarding the trustworthiness, they look safe, tidy and transparent. I can't find any bad word-of-mouth on the web.